# How do I prevent wallpaper from being zoomed

Tags: java, android, eclipse

At Last I found one problem on setting the Image as wallpaper the image gets zoomed in.. Here is the screen shot of the image selection i made inside the app(First pic) after setting it has Wallpaper it appears like this(Second pic)

[image]
[image]

The code for this is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

that was not what i selected. Everything is zoomed in, any Help?
if anything else needed please tell me to upload it,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

also perhaps removing layout gravity center.